# Eclipse CDT: error: '::wcstold' has not been declared using MinGW

Tags: c++, eclipse, stl, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to compile my game, originally written in VC++, in Eclipse CDT. I've downloaded MinGW from their website. I get this error when I'm compiling:

> c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/cwchar:250:11:
>   error: '::wcstold' has not been declared
>   c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/cwchar:266:22:
>   error: '__gnu_cxx::wcstold' has not been declared

Why are they not defined? Is there something I forgot to include?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. I installed cygwin on the same system and accidentally added the include files provided by cygwin to the project configuration.

Removing cygwin's include files from CDTs "C/C++ General" -> "Paths and Symbols" -> "Includes" window solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't do wrong thing. It's caused by MinGW has some delay to port the new Windows API.

See [this blog post](http://kane-mx.blogspot.com/2011/08/create-import-library-for-building.html) for how resolve this issue.

Comment: Hm are you sure about this? Im not sure if I'm using the Windows API. Perheps ogre does, but the problem is related to an inclusion of <string>

Answer (score 0):

If your game uses SDL you should download diffetent libraries, VC++ and Mingw use diferent libraries and headers

Comment: Im using Ogre3D SDK. I downloaded the MinGW SDK version, so it must be able somehow to compile. It's also the Ogre header which includes <string>.